# php date less than another date

Tags: php, date, compare, strtotime

given this kind of date object 
`date("m/d/Y", strtotime($numerical." ".$day." of ".date("F")))`

where it may give a mm/dd/yyyy day that is the "first Monday of August", for instance

how can I decide if this date is greater than, less than, or equal to today's date?

I need a `now()` method that works in this format and can be compared between date objects

I haven't tried date() < date() , yet. But I don't think that will work

any insight appreciated

Comment: You don't think it will work? Why not try it?

Comment: @DanyCaissy he wants to compare date()'s output, not the integer timestamp…

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Compare the timestamps:

```
if (strtotime($numerical." ".$day." of ".date("F")) < time()) {
    // older
} else {
    // newer
}
```

This is possible as `strtotime()` returns the seconds since 1.1.1970 and `time()` too. And in PHP you can easily compare integers...