# php check expire date if older than user expire date postbone to user expire date

Tags: php, validation, date

i creating someting to user submit a post, its have a expire date to not show,
im tring to overide the post expire date if user is stil valid in system ,
if user is have a date witch greater than post expire date and todays date let the post be active,

here i set user expire date to future but i tryed older time both returend me 
this `post have time to expire`
im stuck and confused at this point and sorry if there is bad typo.
thankyou

note 
thankyou all this code is working

```
  $links_user = 'testuser';
  $d_vexpdate = new DateTime('2014-09-05');// user valid until date
  $d_postexp = new DateTime('2014-08-20');// post expire date 2 weeks later
  $d_postpub = new DateTime('2014-08-06');// post submit date
  $d_today = new DateTime();
  $d_old = new DateTime('-14 day');

if ($d_vexpdate > $d_today && $d_postexp < $d_today){
        echo "<br> post expire is great than today :)<br>";
      }

   }else {
    echo "hello expired - ".$links_user;

    }
```

Comment: Where is `$today` coming from, or is that just an example?

Comment: oops im totaly forgot that to put here + im confused totaly

Comment: TBH Sara, I have a hard time with "time-related" code and have just spent the better part of 2 days in trying to figure something out, which is similar to what you want to do. This page helped me a lot http://www.highlystructured.com/comparing_dates_php.html - I know exactly how you feel, I was just as confused; still am to a certain point lol

Comment: fred there is user expire date witch has to override post expire date and today to be valid icant figure it out how :(

Comment: I just finished today figuring out my issue, TBH, my head is complete mush after all that. Do look at the link I gave you and take it from there; it's the best I can do.

Comment: See also these Q&A's that helped me to a certain extent http://stackoverflow.com/q/17329281/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/25316200/ but this one http://www.highlystructured.com/comparing_dates_php.html is the one that helped me the most.

Comment: thankyou fred im going turn my head to mush too :) at this moment im burend all my curcuit in my brain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime('-14 days')` Includes the current time, so is giving the timestamp for e.g. 2014-08-06 00:01:15 where as `strtotime('2014-08-06')` leaves the time values at zero as they aren't specified i.e. the timestamp for 2014-08-06 00:00:00, which is therefore less than the expiry timestamp, causing the first condition to be true.

Try using the built in DateTime class to help with this:

```
//...
$d_postpub = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2014-08-06 00:00:00');
$cutoff = new DateTime('-14 days'); $cutoff->setTime(0,0,0);
if($d_postpub<$cutoff){
//...
```

Comment: hi thankyou for respond but where is $d_vexpdate it has to override $cutoff so if 14 days expired can be valid with $d_vexpdate date untill $d_vexpdate is less than today -thankyou

Comment: You can define the other dates you need in the same way as $d_postpub. Any string that is valid for strtotime can be used when creating a DateTime object. $today can be created even more simply as `new DateTime()` defaults to the current date and time.

Comment: tankyou kami 'new DateTime' was the answer i couldent figure to validate date and thanks to fred too . @fred-ii